# Permutations and Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, permutations

I was going through the problem that I have mentioned below. Included is the proposed solution, however, I want to be crystal clear about the reasoning behind the expressions used to compute the conditional probabilities:

> An urn has 'r' red balls and 'w' white balls that are removed one at a time randomly. Let $R_i$ be the event where the $i^\text{th}$ ball is red. Compute:
>
> (1) $ P(R_i) $ 
> (2) $ P(R_5 \mid R_3 ) $
>
> (1) All balls are distinguishable (with ordering), thus giving the number of permutations of 'i' balls: 
>  
> $$ = \frac{(r+w)!}{(r+w-i)!}$$
>
>  
> Outcomes in $ R_i =$ ($r$ ways to chose $i^\text{th}$ ball) $\cdot \left( \frac{(r + w - 1)!}{(r + w - 1 - (i -1))!} \right) = r \cdot \frac{(r+w-1)!}{(r+w-i)!}$ 
>
> [Shouldn't the numerator be $(r+w)!$.**Why are already we assuming one ball has been taken? Is it because we are simply calculating the permutations of the remaining balls?** This seems pretty obvious because otherwise the probability will become $r$ which is obviously not true, but it still doesn't explain my question.]
>
> $ \therefore P(R_i) = \dfrac{ \frac{(r + w -1)!}{(r + w -i)!} }{\frac{(r+w)!}{(r+w-i)!}} $ 
>  
> $ \therefore P(R_i) = \dfrac{r(r+w-1)}{(r+w)!} = \dfrac{r}{r+w}$
>
> (2) In this part the calculation of $ P(R_5 \cap R_3) $ seems to follow the same principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are we dividing by the number of balls left?

$^{(r+w)}{\rm P}_{i} = \frac{(r+w)!}{(r+w-i)!}$ is the count of ways to extract $i$ distinct balls (line them up in order of extraction).

$^{(r+w)}{\rm P}_{i} = {^{(r+w)}{\rm C}_{i}}\times i!$

> Shouldn't the numerator be $(r+w)!$ since $i=1$ is a possibility. Why are already we assuming one ball has been taken? Is it because we are simply calculating the permutations of the remaining balls?]

Yes.    $^{(r+w-1)}{\rm P}_{(i-1)} = \frac{(r+w-1)!}{(r+w-1-(i-1))!}$ is the count of ways to extract $i-1$ distinct balls before extracting a particular one in the $i$-th place.   When that $i$-th ball is given, there are only $r+w-1$ from which to select the others.

> Why does this expression have $(r+w)$, the the total initial number in denominator's numerator?]

$$\require{cancel}\frac{(r+w-1)!}{(r+w)!} = \frac{\color{silver}{\cancel{\color{black}{(r+w-1)(r+w-2)\cdots 1}}}}{(r+w)\color{silver}{\cancel{\color{black}{(r+w-1)(r+w-2)\cdots 1}}}} \\ \qquad\qquad =\frac{1}{r+w}$$